# Android getting points of a specific direction in some meters in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, location, shapes, direction

I am able to get current direction when i walk. What i try to make is drawing an arc or quarter `circle` to my direction and getting edge points of my `circle`.

Actually i am trying to get 3 `points`. I am able to get my current `location`. The other 2 locations are the edge points of my arc in my `direction`. It is not a must drawing arc or circle to my direction. Maybe drawing `polygon` is acceptable for me.

Can you help me to find out a solution on this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can start reading the documentation of [Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes) in the Google Maps Android API, it explains here some simple ways to add shapes to your maps in order to customize them for your application.

- [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) is a series of connected line segments that can form any shape you want and can be used to mark paths and routes on the map.

The Polyline class defines a set of connected line segments on the map. It also consists of a set of LatLng locations, and creates a series of line segments that connect those locations in an ordered sequence. Just check the this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polylines) on how to create Polylines

- [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) is an object that are similar to Polyline objects in that they consist of a series of coordinates in an ordered sequence. However, instead of being open-ended, polygons are designed to define regions within a closed loop with the interior filled in. You can add a Polygon to the map in the same way as you add a Polyline.
- [Circles](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) is a geographically accurate projection of a circle on the Earth's surface drawn on the map.

The following code snippet adds a circle to the map by constructing a `CircleOptions` object and calling [`GoogleMap.addCircle(CircleOptions)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#addCircle(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions)):

```
// Instantiates a new CircleOptions object and defines the center and radius
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
    .radius(1000)); // In meters

// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

For more sample code check the documentation and this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#code_samples).